# need cloudinary image and video sample code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I need a sample code for image and video upload to cloudinary in jquery. I don't know how to upload the image with cloudinary in jquery.

I have read this "http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud" documentation. But there is no proper documentation for jquery.

Please guys provide me a guide with steps, if you have implement cloudinary image/video upload with jquery.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary's server-side SDKs are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/cloudinary). They include sample projects which demonstrate uploading to Cloudinary. For example, in PHP:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/master/samples/PhotoAlbum